# How to use the pulseaudio API as root?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I am currently trying to use the pulseaudio [simple API](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/simple.html) to record microphone data from my USB sound card with my raspberry pi 3. I used the example program [parec-simple](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/parec-simple_8c-example.html) from pulseaudio in my own program and it works quite nice.

The program i used this code for is accessing gpio's so i need to run this as root. However, when i try to execute the program as root, i get the following errors:

```
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
W: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to open configuration file '/root/.config/pulse//daemon.conf': Permission denied
W: [pulseaudio] daemon-conf.c: Failed to open configuration file: Permission denied
pa_simple_new() failed: Connection refused
```

the code is used is the following:

```
static const pa_sample_spec ss = {
    .format = PA_SAMPLE_S16LE,
    .rate = 44100,
    .channels = 1
};
pa_simple *s = NULL;
int ret = 1;
int error;
/* Create the recording stream */
if (!(s = pa_simple_new(NULL, argv[0], PA_STREAM_RECORD, NULL, "record", &ss, NULL, NULL, &error))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "pa_simple_new() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
    goto finish;
}



while(1)
{
    uint8_t buf[BUFSIZE];
    /* Record some data ... */
    if (pa_simple_read(s, buf, sizeof(buf), &error) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_read() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
        goto finish;
    }

    /* And write it to STDOUT */
    if (loop_write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf)) != sizeof(buf)) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": write() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto finish;
    }

}
   ret = 0;
finish:
    if (s)
        pa_simple_free(s);
    return ret;
```

I already tried `chown pi:pi /home/pi` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/338574) to try to fix it but it doesn't work. changing the owner of /home/pi from pi to root didn't work for me either.

I also tried a clean reinstall of pulseaudio but unfortunately it didn't fix it.

So what can i do to fix these errors?

Comment: try `sudo ./a.out`, :p. Or `chmod +r "/root/.config/pulse//daemon.conf"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran `chmod +r "/root/.config/pulse//daemon.conf"` and it returns `chmod: cannot access ‘/root/.config/pulse//daemon.conf’: No such file or directory`.

Comment: It seems you miss a file. Search for pulse/daemon.conf from another user (/home/username/.confg etc), and copy that file in your location (creating missing directories if needed).

Answer (score 2):

When you run process with sudo it does not change Home directory to `/root` - `sudo echo $HOME # /home/username`. You need to specify HOME directory with by running `sudo HOME=/root executable`.

When you want to access pulseaudio from root you need to run it system wide with command - `sudo pulseaudio --system=true`.

Then you will receive an error from pulseaudio:

```
W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
```

Which can be solved by adding `root` user to `audio-pulse` group - `sudo adduser root pulse-access`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run your program as user root, then you must impersonate root. I don't know if pulseaudio looks at the username in order to find configuration files, or it looks at the $HOME variable. In the second case, maybe that by setting HOME to the home of a "working" user helps.

Anyway what you told about the situation is clear: pulseaudio does not find a file:

> '/root/.config/pulse//daemon.conf'

Place a correct "daemon.conf" in that directory - probably you can copy it from somewhere (like /home/auser/.config/pulse/daemon.conf).

Consider that directories with name starting with a dot are normally hidden; if using a file manager you must enable "show hidden files", if you use the shell, `ls -a` can help.

Your first target is to confirm that the file is there, and your program should not complain about a missing/unreadable config file. Then, maybe other errors will show up but, one after another, you can eliminate them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I copied daemon.conf from /etc/pulse/ to /root/.config/pulse/, because /home/username/.config/pulse doesn't have a daemon.conf. After rebooting the program does not complain about permissions anymore, which is good. However, the `pa_simple_new() failed: Connection refused` error still persist.. 

Other suggestions?

Comment: I know almost nothing about pulse... Check that the pulseaudio server is running, note its listening port, and check that daemon.conf does not have conflicting settings with the situation. Unfortunately I can't say more, sorry.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. Everything seems fine with the configuration but it won't work.

Comment: You should post some more data, like the daemon.conf, and the global configuration of pulseaudio, to check that your program is trying to connect to the right host & port. You can do it in this question or, perhaps better, a new one. But you should collect and publish data: it is clear that pulseaudio server is not running, or it is listening to a certain port, but your program addresses another port (or another host). You must read a lot about pulseaudio configuration.

Comment: Changing the HOME env variable is not best practice, though it works.

Comment: @fiorentinoing of course changing HOME is wrong but, as a debugging test, it can help.